# Specimen STEP question

Tags: inequality

Show by using the binomial expansion, or otherwise, that $(1+x)^{n}>nx$
whenever $x\geqslant0$ and $n$ is a positive integer. Deduce that
if $y>1$ then, given any number $K$, an integer $N$ can be found
such that $y^{n}>K$ for all integers $n\geqslant N.$

Show further that if $y>1$ then, given any $K$, an integer $N$
can be found such that $\dfrac{y^{n}}{n}>K$ for all integers $n\geqslant N$.

I can show the inequality in the first sentence (using binomial expansion).

However I'm not clear about what is being asked in the remaining parts of the question. Surely any number larger than 1 can be made as large as you like by taking a sufficiently large n. What is the question getting at by asking to deduce this from the inequality in the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that, intuitively, we all know that $1.1^n$ gets bigger without bound as $n$ increases. The point of the question is ostensibly to prove this formally, but in fact it is there to give you a hint as to how you might tackle the "Show further" part, which is less 'obviously' true (though we might well also intuitively know that $1.1^n$ gets bigger much faster than $n$ as $n$ increases).

To use the result, let $x=y-1$, then $$y^n > n(y-1) \geqslant N(y-1)$$ for $y>1$, $n\geqslant N$. Can you see how to choose $N$ to make sure this is always larger than $K$?

Then can you see how to adapt the argument of the first paragraph to prove the result in the second paragraph?